# SQL: Best practice to store various fields in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-design

I want to design a table for items.
There are many types of items, all share several fields.
Each type of item has it's own fields.
I want to store the uncommon fields in a separate table.
I thought of something like :

```
----Items
+Item_id
+Item_Type_Id
+Item_Serial
...

----Item_types
+Item_Type_Id
+Item_Name
...

----Item_Fields
+Item_Field_Id
+Item_Type_Id
+Field_Name
...

----Field_Values
+Field_Value_Id
+Item_Field_Id
+Item_Id
+Value
...
```

The pro is having the ability to add fields and values without changing the tables.
The con is that i have to transpose the field names and values in order to see all info for an item.

Any better suggestions? Or perhaps a simple (not stored procedure) way to join the tables to get a flat info?
I tried to use PIVOT (I'm using SQL 2005) but with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Use PIVOT (with luck this time)

Comment: PIVOT uses IN (string of column names)...
In my case column names are coming from a table, and i need to concatenate them into string. Any simple way doing in it in sql without using stored procedures?

Comment: Ugh! Stay away from the Name-Value pair design. It's nothing but trouble in the end. There are VERY few instances where its flexibility makes up for the other problems that it causes. Everything always thinks that there situation is one of those instances, but they very rarely are. If your table needs a new column, add a new column. You should be thinking about data types, lengths, constraints, etc. anyway when adding a new data element to your application/database.

Comment: Thank you Tom, but if i will add all the columns I need to one table I will use only small number of them for each item and the rest will be NULL's. I'll get 4 columns of data for one item and 5 other columns for another item... That doesn't seem like a good solution, doesn't it?
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Leon- This leads to the question "are all of these actually the same thing, and should they be in the same table"?

Comment: Yes Donnie, I thought about it too.

The items are equipment used by workers. so it can be a PC,Phone, Screen, Keyboard etc. all f them share some basic info and if i'll use different tables it will be difficult to represent all of them and make calculations such as sum of prices etc.

Comment: I'm not sure the EAV design deserves the garbage can so quickly.  I wrote about this recently: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a stored proc to make PIVOT more useful.  Here is the source:

http://dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query.sql

and some examples how to use it:

http://dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query_examples.sql

For your data, the query would just be the raw data joining those tables above to produce a raw listing of:

```
set @myQuery = '
 Select Item_Id, Item_Name, Field_Name, Value From ...
';
```

Then your call to pivot_query would be:

```
exec pivot_query @myQuery, 'Item_Id, Item_Name', 'Field_Name', 'max(Value)'
```

like that.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to store items in XML format in one single field. Depending on your usage scenario, it may work well. Or it may not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there has to be some grouping of values.

For example lets say your items are objects in a room.  Then different types of objects have different attributes.  For example books have publication date and number of pages, chairs have color pattern and height, etc.

In this example, you make an item table, a book table and a chair table.

You could make an "additional values" table that holds generic information as above, but what you really want to do is figure out the "types" of the different groups of attributes and then make every one of those types it's own table.

Is there a set of values that all items have?  There has to be at least one which is a type field (this describes where the other information is stored.  I expect every item will also have a name and a description.  This is the information to go in the item table.

Then you make additional tables for the different types itembook, itemchair etc.  There may even be some overlap.  For example itembook, itemhardback, itempaperback would be 3 tables used to describe books.

I believe this is the best solution to your problem.  It will still allow you to extend, but it does put a framework around your data.

Of course there are systems that do it the way you describe, but unless you are building a tool that others are going to reuse for many different projects, it makes sense to design the system for the task at hand.  You end up falling into the over designing trap otherwise. (IMHO)

On the other hand, if you are going to go the totally generic direction I suggest you use one of the systems that already exist that work in this way (entity framework, app framework, etc)  Use someone else's don't start from scratch.

Comment: Hogan, Thank you for the detailed answer. Yes, it is a little bit over design (you know how bosses are) but if i use additional tables i will have to use specific queries for each type. 

Or do you know how i can select from a table which name is stored in another table? I guess i could store the table name along with the item_type and use stored procedure to somehow select from it...

Comment: Well the best way is to just do a left join to all the detail tables if you are doing something that requires all the values.  I expect you  will often only need data from a sub-set of all the tables.  This is where you gain optimization.  Also, you could just make a view that has all these joins in it and use that to select your data.

Comment: ahhh... wrote the above before I read @onsaito.  What he said.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure how you want to retrieve the info, but something like the below may work. (It's probably close to what Hogan mentioned.)

- If you want to retrieve data for a type, you can just JOIN two tables.
- If you want to retrieve data for all types (with all fields), you can LEFT JOIN all tables.

---

```
----Items
+Item_id
+Item_Type_Id
+Item_Common_Field1
+Item_Common_Field1
...

----Item_Type_A
+Item_id
+Item_Type_A_Specific_Field1
+Item_Type_A_Specific_Field2
...

----Item_Type_B
+Item_id
+Item_Type_B_Specific_Field1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add these columns to the table, you can make them *sparse* columns to avoid the space taken by unspecified uncommon fields.

But I would *not* call this a best practice. (see comments under your question)

Comment: I agree. That's why I asked for help\suggestions.
Both ways seem to have big disadvantages. I tried to search for a "Best Practice" on the matter but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be accused of being the always-uses-the-latest-useless-technology guy, but depending on your use case, this might be a good case for a nosql database - Tokyo, Mongo, SimpleDB, etc. Or as Developer Art suggested, you could just serialize the different fields into a single column. It's not the worst thing in the world.

Comment: In this case i really do need a relational database and perform a lot of joining, aggregation and reporting, so i don't think that a nosql solution can work for me this time.